# При сужении браузера, видно классы @media. Но мобильные телефоны не видят

Tags: html, css, mobile

Мне достался сайт для добавления адаптивного дизайна, обычный лендинг без какой либо CMS. Обычно я верстаю адаптивный дизайн при помощи

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

Но почему то этот лендинг не видит классы внутри @media screen когда открываешь на каком либо телефоне и через "просмотреть код" в гугл хроме (toglle device tollbar). Вот что расположено а head:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Ремонт кофемашин</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/favicon.png" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" media="all" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Пробовал добавлять код с css классами

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {....}
```

и в style.css и в page.css и в сам index.html через  - ничего не дало результатов. Может кто то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией, помогите.

Comment: Добавьте в head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` и скрипты лучше перед закрывающим `</body>` вставлять

Comment: Да, всё получилось. А можно ли сделать так, что бы при перевёртывании телефона в горизонтальное положение, сайт был виден сразу во всю ширину, как на компьютере, что бы не нужно было пальцами отдалять?

Comment: Без css кода не могу ответить

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо и на этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

в хеад добавте...

Comment: Да, всё получилось. А можно ли сделать так, что бы при перевёртывании телефона в горизонтальное положение, сайт был виден сразу во всю ширину, как на компьютере, что бы не нужно было пальцами отдалять?